# Nether portal mismatches

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made an overworld portal (Portal A) at `[x:-21, z:233]`. This took me to a new portal in the nether (Portal C) which as at `[x:-4, z:41]`.

I then went to another location in the overworld and created Portal B at `[x:-613, z:-373]`. This is a total of around 1200 blocks away so I thought it was a safe distance. However, when I stepped through, I arrived at Portal C again.

So, I tore down Portal C and used a [Portal coordinates calculator](http://mavenspun.com/games/minecraft/) to tell me where Portal B's match in the Nether should be. The calculator gave me `[x:-77, z:-46]`, so I went there and constructed Portal D.

When I stepped through Portal D, I ended up at portal B, as I expected. So I ran back to Portal A, and stepped through it again.. only to end up at portal D in the Nether. When I stepped back through portal D, I ended up at portal B.

What's happening is this:

`A -> D <-> B`

Whereas what I want to happen is this:

`A <-> C` and `B <-> D`

How can I achieve this? I don't mind tearing down portals, but I'd rather avoid that as it's quite time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

The answer:  Enter the nether and manually put portal C back.  Then you will have two sets of portals which work the way you want.

---

Explanation: Nether coordinates correspond to overworld coordinates divided by 8.  The portal coordinates calculator you link to is simply multiplying or dividing by 8 depending on which coordinates you enter.

When you enter a portal in the overworld it calculates the destination nether coordinates.  It then searches a bounding area of 128 blocks from that destination coordinate and selects the closest active portal.  This searches a bounding square of 257 X 257 blocks.  This is the destination coordinates plus and minus 128.

If it does not locate one in that bounding area, it creates one.

In your case you constructed portal A, entered it.  It calculated (-3, ,29) as the destination.  It then searched a square from (125, ,157) to (-131, ,-99). It found no portals, so it searched for the closest suitable area and created portal C.

You then traveled -592X and -606Z blocks away (not 1200) and constructed portal B.  When you entered it, it calculated (-77, ,-47) as the destination.  It then searched a square from (-205, ,-175) to (51, ,81) and it located portal C so you exited there.  (128 nether x 8 = 1024 overworld)

When you entered portal C the closest overworld portal was portal A so you exited there.

You tore down portal C and built portal D.  Entered portal D which exited portal B as it was closer then portal A.  Entered portal A which exited portal D as portal C is gone and Portal D is within the 128 range.  Entered portal D to once again exit portal B as it is closer.

So the solution is to reconstruct portal C.  It should have never been torn down in the first place.

For more information visit the [wiki on portal linkage](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_portal#Portal_linkage_between_Overworld_and_Nether).

Comment: [Here is an answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/317818/186522) I gave that also has some information that may help you if you are building several sets of portals.  For part of the answer, I carefully build two sets of portals back to back and they work successfully.

Comment: But Portal C and portal D are 160 blocks away from eachother (`-73` on the X axis and `-87` on the Y axis), this is further than the 128 blocks in which it searches for an active portal.

Comment: I edited my answer to include some more information on the search routine.  The search area is plus and minus 128 in both directions.  Both 73 and 87 are below 128 and so it is within the search area.